# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' error while installing Sitecore Azure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-azure

I want to deploy my website (built in sitecore 8.0) in Azure using Sitcore Azure module. I have downloaded the Sitecore azure 8.0 module from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure/80/Sitecore_Azure_80.aspx . And started installation using Installation wizard, I got an error after around 2 hours are spent on installation process. The error saying "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' : Failed to load 'sitecoredemo/.../InstallationWizard'.

How to proceed further, please suggest.

Comment: What version of Sitecore Azure module did you try to install? Was it `8.0 rev. 161110`? Which version of Sitecore XP 8.0 do you use?

Comment: The version is Sitecore Azure 8.0 rev. 150522 and for Sitecore XP it is Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150621

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I got the issue, mongodb instance was not running. I have started the same and after that installation is sucessfull. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you was able to fix it!

Please get aquatinted with the following article regarding Sitecore Azure module: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/013487